# Issue with AssociationSet in EF when changing target from .NET 4.0 to 3.5

Tags: entity-framework, associations, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I developed a **Repository** component targeting the **.NET 4 Framework** that uses **EF**. In my EF I use tables already existing in the **Database**.

In the Database I have 4 tables representing **entities** and **3 association tables** (the relationships between the entities are all many-to-many)

However these tables at Database level **do not** have any **relation** between each other. Since I do not have rights to modify the Database, I added the relations directly in the EF. I named them, I specified the navigation properties and then I successfully compiled and tested the project.

Now I have to reference this Repository project from a **Web application** using the **.NET 3.5**. Therefore also the Repository project must reference the .NET 3.5.

I correctly copied the connection string from the Repository project to the **web.config**, I compiled the project and...it gives me a compile error saying that there is

> "no mapping specified between EntitySet/AssociationSet"

and then lists the relationships between tables/entities.

I guess this error is given because there are no associations at Database level. How can I solve this issue without having to rewrite all my code?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an EF 4 EDMX in EF 3.5 period. You can, however, use an EF 3.5 EDMX in EF 4, but the EF 4 designer won't understand it.

One possible fix is to make your EF 4 project an out of process server.

Comment: Thanks. What about deleting the edmx, set the project to target the 3.5 and create the edmx again? Will it do the job?

Comment: It worked but now it gives me an error with Closures. It seems it has a little problem with the Any() method